# MySQL Syntax error when inserting

Tags: php, mysql

I've got a syntax error in the following code, but I can't find it:

```
$tableSelect = $_POST["tableSelect"];
$companyName = $_POST["companyName"];
$telephone = $_POST["telephone"];
$fax = $_POST["fax"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$address = $_POST["address"];
$postcode = $_POST["postcode"];
$category = $_POST["category"];
$contact = $_POST["contact"];
$contactTel = $_POST["contactTel"];
$contactEmail = $_POST["contactEmail"];
$sql = "INSERT INTO '" . $tableSelect . "' ('" . $companyName . "', '" . $telephone . "', '"
    . $fax . "', '" . $email . "', '" . $address . "','" . $postcode . "', '" . $category . "',
    '" . $contact . "', '" . $contactTel . "', '" . $contactEmail . "')";
mysqli_query($con,$sql);
if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
```

Cheers!

**EDIT:** I have modified the code to this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `" . $tableSelect . "` (name, telephone, fax, email, address, postcode, category,
    contact, contactTel, contactEmail) VALUES (`" . $companyName . "`, `" . $telephone . "`, `"
    . $fax . "`, `" . $email . "`, `" . $address . "`,`" . $postcode . "`, `" . $category . "`,
    `" . $contact . "`, `" . $contactTel . "`, `" . $contactEmail . "`)";
```

and now have the error "Error: Unknown column [companyName] in 'field list'", where [companyName] is the value submitted through the form. But surely I've defined the column as "name"?

**Edit 2:** Thanks, I'm now aware of the injection issue. I'd like to get it working, then I'll change it to using prepared statements.

Comment: poor bobby tables :( - http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: Aside from injection, it seems to me that you've still got no VALUES, no values at all.

Comment: **You are leaving yourself wide open to SQL injection attacks.**  Also, any input data with single quotes in it, like a name of "O'Malley", will blow up your SQL query. Please learn about using parametrized queries, preferably with the PDO module, to protect your web app.  http://bobby-tables.com/php has examples to get you started.

Comment: Don't quote/backtick your column & table names.  They only add visual clutter and are just one more way for you to make syntax errors.  The only reason you need them is if you have a column name that is a reserved word, and using column names that are reserved words is a terrible idea, so that's two bad habits you can avoid at once.

Comment: @Strawberry I've only added the code that I've changed, so the values are still there. And yes, guys, I'm aware of the injection issue now ;p I'll get it working first, then sort that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring injection issues...

```
$sql = "
INSERT INTO $tableSelect 
(name
,telephone
,fax
,email
,address
,postcode
,category
,contact
,contactTel
,contactEmail
) VALUES 
('$companyName'
,'$telephone'
,'$fax'
,'$email'
,'$address'
,'$postcode'
,'$category'
,'$contact'
,'$contactTel'
,'$contactEmail'
);
";
```

Incidentally, in my (limited) experience, the practice of calling the variable (e.g. '$companyName') and the column (e.g. `name`) two (slightly) different things can get very confusing.

Comment: You sir, are a gentleman and a scholar. I shall now sort the injection issues before everyone goes apeshit on my ass ;)

Comment: You're welcome. If it's not obvious, I suppose I should point out that I have no formal qualification in MySQL (or computing generally) - oh, and my profile is supposed to be 'non-gender specific' ;-)

Comment: I do apologise ;p You, Madam, are a lady and a scholar. I'm having some trouble with the prepared-statement version though - don't suppose you could help me out on that?

Answer (score 2):

You need either a `values` statement or a `select` statement:

```
"INSERT INTO '" . $tableSelect . "' VALUES ('" . $companyName . "', '" . $telephone . "', '"
. $fax . "', '" . $email . "', '" . $address . "','" . $postcode . "', '" . $category . "',
'" . $contact . "', '" . $contactTel . "', '" . $contactEmail . "')";
```

However, I would also recommend that you include the column names in the `insert` statement:

```
"INSERT INTO '" . $tableSelect ."(companyname, telephone, fax, email, address, postcode, category, contact, contactTel, contactEmail) ".
  "' VALUES ('" . $companyName . "', '" . $telephone . "', '"
. $fax . "', '" . $email . "', '" . $address . "','" . $postcode . "', '" . $category . "',
'" . $contact . "', '" . $contactTel . "', '" . $contactEmail . "')";
```

I'm not sure if those are the correct names.

Comment: I've included the VALUES and the column names - could you take a look at my edit?

Answer (score 1):

Use backquotes: ` instead of straight quotes when quoting table names:

instead of:

```
'" . $companyName . "'
```

this:

```
`" . $companyName . "`
```

Use prepared statements instead of putting the variables into the query directly. And check, that the tables names are correct, cause now you are open to SQL injection.

[How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php/60496#60496)

Answer (score 1):

> please check insert query syntax
>
> you are missing **values** in your program:
>
> Follow the below Syntax:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3,...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...)
```

Answer (score 0):

try query like this

```
$query="insert into abc (a,b,c) values ('a','b','c')

and first check your all variables using isset()
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below query:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO $tableSelect ('" . $companyName."', '".$telephone."',
'".$fax."', '".$email."', '".$address."', '".$postcode."', '".$category."',
'".$contact."', '".$contactTel."', '".$contactEmail."')";
```

If still getting error, then you should use mysql_real_escape_string() function.
Data may contain special characters.